# How can I read Solana historic transactions directly from Arweave?

Tags: arweave

Any hints on how/where on Arweave I can access the historic ledger, archived by the Solar Bridge, highly appreciated.

Comment: GenesysGo is working on a solution for that. I don't know if it has already been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge that project is not being actively maintained